# JSON invalid format

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize the JSON from the weather API, I have created C# classes but I can't seem to get it working. Most sites display this JSON as invalid format, so I'm not really sure whats wrong with it. Here is the JSON string and my class for Deserializing.Visual studio displays it like any other regular JSON.

```
"[\"cod\":\"200\",\"message\":0,\"cnt\":40,\"list\":[[\"dt\":1574175600,\"main\":[\"temp\":284.79,\"temp_min\":282.63,\"temp_max\":284.79,\"pressure\":1021,\"sea_level\":1021,\"grnd_level\":958,\"humidity\":88,\"temp_kf\":2.16],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3,\"deg\":51],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-19 15:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574186400,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.92,\"temp_min\":281.3,\"temp_max\":282.92,\"pressure\":1021,\"sea_level\":1021,\"grnd_level\":958,\"humidity\":94,\"temp_kf\":1.62],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.93,\"deg\":53],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-19 18:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574197200,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.6,\"temp_min\":281.52,\"temp_max\":282.6,\"pressure\":1021,\"sea_level\":1021,\"grnd_level\":957,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":1.08],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.84,\"deg\":64],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-19 21:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574208000,\"main\":[\"temp\":281.67,\"temp_min\":281.13,\"temp_max\":281.67,\"pressure\":1020,\"sea_level\":1020,\"grnd_level\":956,\"humidity\":94,\"temp_kf\":0.54],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.83,\"deg\":65],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 00:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574218800,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.97,\"temp_min\":280.97,\"temp_max\":280.97,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":96,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.9,\"deg\":57],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 03:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574229600,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.72,\"temp_min\":280.72,\"temp_max\":280.72,\"pressure\":1016,\"sea_level\":1016,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":96,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":90],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.65,\"deg\":65],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 06:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574240400,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.34,\"temp_min\":282.34,\"temp_max\":282.34,\"pressure\":1015,\"sea_level\":1015,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":91,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.32,\"deg\":78],\"rain\":[\"3h\":1.19],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 09:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574251200,\"main\":[\"temp\":283.44,\"temp_min\":283.44,\"temp_max\":283.44,\"pressure\":1015,\"sea_level\":1015,\"grnd_level\":952,\"humidity\":87,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.16,\"deg\":79],\"rain\":[\"3h\":1.94],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 12:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574262000,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.5,\"temp_min\":282.5,\"temp_max\":282.5,\"pressure\":1015,\"sea_level\":1015,\"grnd_level\":952,\"humidity\":90,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.21,\"deg\":75],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 15:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574272800,\"main\":[\"temp\":281.27,\"temp_min\":281.27,\"temp_max\":281.27,\"pressure\":1016,\"sea_level\":1016,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":88,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":80],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.94,\"deg\":105],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.38],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 18:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574283600,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.14,\"temp_min\":280.14,\"temp_max\":280.14,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":90,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":0],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.72,\"deg\":131],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.19],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-20 21:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574294400,\"main\":[\"temp\":279.7,\"temp_min\":279.7,\"temp_max\":279.7,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":89,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":0],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.53,\"deg\":122],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 00:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574305200,\"main\":[\"temp\":279.29,\"temp_min\":279.29,\"temp_max\":279.29,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":89,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":0],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.71,\"deg\":110],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 03:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574316000,\"main\":[\"temp\":278.99,\"temp_min\":278.99,\"temp_max\":278.99,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":90,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":0],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.76,\"deg\":106],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 06:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574326800,\"main\":[\"temp\":284.12,\"temp_min\":284.12,\"temp_max\":284.12,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":71,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"clear sky\",\"icon\":\"01d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":0],\"wind\":[\"speed\":1.91,\"deg\":94],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 09:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574337600,\"main\":[\"temp\":286.38,\"temp_min\":286.38,\"temp_max\":286.38,\"pressure\":1016,\"sea_level\":1016,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":62,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":801,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"few clouds\",\"icon\":\"02d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":21],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.19,\"deg\":66],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 12:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574348400,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.01,\"temp_min\":282.01,\"temp_max\":282.01,\"pressure\":1016,\"sea_level\":1016,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":91,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.67,\"deg\":46],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 15:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574359200,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.86,\"temp_min\":280.86,\"temp_max\":280.86,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":94,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":86],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.78,\"deg\":49],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 18:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574370000,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.55,\"temp_min\":280.55,\"temp_max\":280.55,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":92,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.52,\"deg\":56],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-21 21:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574380800,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.04,\"temp_min\":280.04,\"temp_max\":280.04,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":95,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.6,\"deg\":53],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 00:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574391600,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.1,\"temp_min\":280.1,\"temp_max\":280.1,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":96,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.54,\"deg\":49],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 03:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574402400,\"main\":[\"temp\":281.29,\"temp_min\":281.29,\"temp_max\":281.29,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":97,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.24,\"deg\":38],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.44],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 06:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574413200,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.84,\"temp_min\":280.84,\"temp_max\":280.84,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":501,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"moderate rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.21,\"deg\":33],\"rain\":[\"3h\":3.88],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 09:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574424000,\"main\":[\"temp\":279.71,\"temp_min\":279.71,\"temp_max\":279.71,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.37,\"deg\":41],\"rain\":[\"3h\":2.81],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 12:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574434800,\"main\":[\"temp\":278.48,\"temp_min\":278.48,\"temp_max\":278.48,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.59,\"deg\":49],\"rain\":[\"3h\":1.88],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 15:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574445600,\"main\":[\"temp\":278.11,\"temp_min\":278.11,\"temp_max\":278.11,\"pressure\":1019,\"sea_level\":1019,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.55,\"deg\":49],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.81],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 18:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574456400,\"main\":[\"temp\":278.1,\"temp_min\":278.1,\"temp_max\":278.1,\"pressure\":1019,\"sea_level\":1019,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.67,\"deg\":49],\"rain\":[\"3h\":1.38],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-22 21:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574467200,\"main\":[\"temp\":277.43,\"temp_min\":277.43,\"temp_max\":277.43,\"pressure\":1020,\"sea_level\":1020,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":93,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.15,\"deg\":47],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.75],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 00:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574478000,\"main\":[\"temp\":277.23,\"temp_min\":277.23,\"temp_max\":277.23,\"pressure\":1019,\"sea_level\":1019,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":92,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":500,\"main\":\"Rain\",\"description\":\"light rain\",\"icon\":\"10n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":98],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.5,\"deg\":59],\"rain\":[\"3h\":0.56],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 03:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574488800,\"main\":[\"temp\":276.54,\"temp_min\":276.54,\"temp_max\":276.54,\"pressure\":1020,\"sea_level\":1020,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":95,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":98],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.32,\"deg\":59],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 06:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574499600,\"main\":[\"temp\":278.93,\"temp_min\":278.93,\"temp_max\":278.93,\"pressure\":1019,\"sea_level\":1019,\"grnd_level\":955,\"humidity\":86,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.36,\"deg\":56],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 09:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574510400,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.06,\"temp_min\":280.06,\"temp_max\":280.06,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":80,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.74,\"deg\":53],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 12:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574521200,\"main\":[\"temp\":277.41,\"temp_min\":277.41,\"temp_max\":277.41,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":89,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.84,\"deg\":55],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 15:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574532000,\"main\":[\"temp\":276.83,\"temp_min\":276.83,\"temp_max\":276.83,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":92,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":96],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.75,\"deg\":56],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 18:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574542800,\"main\":[\"temp\":277.04,\"temp_min\":277.04,\"temp_max\":277.04,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":90,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":100],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.55,\"deg\":61],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-23 21:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574553600,\"main\":[\"temp\":275.99,\"temp_min\":275.99,\"temp_max\":275.99,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":96,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":803,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"broken clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":81],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.19,\"deg\":55],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-24 00:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574564400,\"main\":[\"temp\":276.56,\"temp_min\":276.56,\"temp_max\":276.56,\"pressure\":1017,\"sea_level\":1017,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":96,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04n\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":91],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.02,\"deg\":62],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"n\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-24 03:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574575200,\"main\":[\"temp\":277.36,\"temp_min\":277.36,\"temp_max\":277.36,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":95,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":804,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"overcast clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":86],\"wind\":[\"speed\":2.99,\"deg\":62],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-24 06:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574586000,\"main\":[\"temp\":280.51,\"temp_min\":280.51,\"temp_max\":280.51,\"pressure\":1018,\"sea_level\":1018,\"grnd_level\":954,\"humidity\":82,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":803,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"broken clouds\",\"icon\":\"04d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":74],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.05,\"deg\":64],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-24 09:00:00\"],[\"dt\":1574596800,\"main\":[\"temp\":282.87,\"temp_min\":282.87,\"temp_max\":282.87,\"pressure\":1016,\"sea_level\":1016,\"grnd_level\":953,\"humidity\":74,\"temp_kf\":0],\"weather\":[[\"id\":802,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"scattered clouds\",\"icon\":\"03d\"]],\"clouds\":[\"all\":42],\"wind\":[\"speed\":3.21,\"deg\":50],\"sys\":[\"pod\":\"d\"],\"dt_txt\":\"2019-11-24 12:00:00\"]],\"city\":[\"id\":787657,\"name\":\"Nis\",\"coord\":[\"lat\":43.3247,\"lon\":21.9033],\"country\":\"RS\",\"timezone\":3600,\"sunrise\":1574141412,\"sunset\":1574175927]]"
```

And my class for deserializing:

```
public class WeatherInfo
{
    public class root
    {
        public string cod { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string cnt { get; set; }
        public allLists list { get; set; }
        public city city { get; set; }
    }

    public class allLists
    {
        allinfo[] allinfos { get; set; }
    }
    public class allinfo
    {
        public string dt { get; set; }
        public main main { get; set; }
        public allWeathers weather { get; set; }
        public string dt_txt { get; set; }
    }

    public class main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public double pressure { get; set; }
        public double sea_level { get; set; }
        public double grnd_level { get; set; }
        public double humidity { get; set; }
        public double temp_kf { get; set; }
    }

    public class allWeathers
    {
        public weather[] weathers { get; set; }
    }

    public class weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class clouds
    {
        public double all { get; set; }
    }

    public class wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public double deg { get; set; }
    }

    public class sys
    {
        public string pod { get; set; }
    }

    public class city
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public coord coord { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string timezone { get; set; }
        public string sunrise { get; set; }
        public string sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class coord
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"can't seem to get it working"_- why not, what error do you get and what have you tried? - _"Most sites display this JSON as invalid format"_ - because it is! Where did you obtain it, what did you do to it?

Comment: In the future when copy pasting string from a debugger you may want to click the magnifying glass icon an copy past the Value instead of the string representation.

Comment: And for json format you can check the documetation http://www.json.org it's pretty clear on what the format should be.

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON is not valid.

The main thing is that you are using brackets `[]` where you should be using braces `{}`.

In JSON `[]` is an array, while `{}` is an object. There are a couple of places where you need to have an array (e.g. `list`) so you can't simply do a find-replace to fix this.

An easy way to resolve this in the future is to create an instance of your `WeatherInfo` class, populate it with data, and then serialize it to JSON. You can then compare that with the JSON you have (using a diff tool like KDiff or WinMerge) to identify where your source JSON is different from your generated JSON.

Comment: `[]` is perfect valid JSON, even at the root.  The problem is their class.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it is, but the OP appears to have replaced every `{}` by `[]`, making the JSON invalid. And _that_ is what the second sentence in this answer says.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, formatting made that difficult to notice.  Checks out!

Comment: Thanks, that should do the trick. Anyways sorry for not mentioning but the data is from openweathermap API, no idea why it's providing me with a invalid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

A valid JSON always starts with a `[` or a `{` and ends with the same, where square bracket `[` represents an array and curly bracket `{` represents an object.

Looking at your C# class, your `JSON` lacks the curly brace to start with for objects and is also missing names for the arrays like `allinfos`.

You should start building your JSON like this:

```
var json = JToken.Parse
("{\"cod\":\"200\",\"message\":0,\"cnt\":40,\"list\":{\"allinfos\":[{\"dt\":1574175600, \"main\":{\"temp\":284.79,\"temp_min\":282.63,\"temp_max\":284.79,\"pressure\":1021,\"sea_level\":1021,\"grnd_level\":958,\"humidity\":88,\"temp_kf\":2.16}}]}}").ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

This will give a formatted, easy to read output like this:

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": {
    "allinfos": [
      {
        "dt": 1574175600,
        "main": {
          "temp": 284.79,
          "temp_min": 282.63,
          "temp_max": 284.79,
          "pressure": 1021,
          "sea_level": 1021,
          "grnd_level": 958,
          "humidity": 88,
          "temp_kf": 2.16
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: The JSON was actually valid, the problem is that I was trying to work with debugging version of the string. The debugger automatically adds escape characters and "" quotes. Also some of the classes I had didn't follow up the JSON format correctly, so that error stopped me from seeing the real issue here.